# Run-time error'91': Object variable or With block variable not set

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have written a procedure within Visual Basic for Application (VBA) in Microsoft Excel 2010. This procedure uses a custom form and asks the user to select an option from the drop-down on the custom form to set a specific range. It then uses that range to loop through a list of name and ask the user to select a file to open so that SUMIFS can be performed in the selected file and inserted into the active document. Although, the procedure fails with the first ** FromWorkbook = Application.GetOpenFilename ** line. Below is the full code:

```
'===============================================================================================
'Description: Loops through the selected site and adds in the vulnerability totals for each _
    systems
'Originally written by: Troy Pilewski
'Date: 2016-06-30
'===============================================================================================

'Declares variables
Dim ToWorkbook As Workbook, FromWorkbook As Workbook
Dim ToWorksheet As Worksheet, FromWorkSheet As Worksheet
Dim WorkingRange As Range, WholeRange As Range, SystemCol As Range, SystemName As Range
Dim FromWorkbookVarient As Variant, ShipNameList() As Variant, ShipName As Variant
Dim TitleString As String, FilterName As String, CurrentSystemName As String, _
    ShipNames() As String, SelectedShipName As String
Dim LastRow As Long, ShipRow As Long
Dim StartRow As Integer, BoundCounter As Integer, MsgSelection As Integer
Const RowMultiplyer As Integer = 47

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set ToWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
Set ToWorksheet = ToWorkbook.ActiveSheet

LastRow = ToWorksheet.Range("Y:Y").Find( _
    What:="*", _
    After:=ToWorksheet.Range("Y1"), _
    LookAt:=xlByRows, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious _
).Row

'MsgBox _
'    Prompt:="Y1:Y" & LastRow, _
'    Title:="Ship Range"

ShipNameList = ToWorksheet.Range("Y1:Y" & LastRow).Value

For Each ShipName In ShipNameList
    If Left(ShipName, 3) = "USS" Then
        BoundCounter = BoundCounter + 1
    End If
Next ShipName

ReDim ShipNames(BoundCounter - 1)
BoundCounter = 0

For Each ShipName In ShipNameList
    If Left(ShipName, 3) = "USS" Then
        ShipNames(BoundCounter) = ShipName
'        Debug.Print ShipNames(BoundCounter)
        BoundCounter = BoundCounter + 1
    Else
'        Debug.Print UBound(ShipNames())
        Exit For
    End If
Next ShipName

TitleString = "Select a ship..."

SelectedShipName = GetChoiceFromChooserForm(ShipNames, TitleString)

If SelectedShipName = "" Then
    Exit Sub
End If

ShipRow = ToWorksheet.Range("Y:Y").Find( _
    What:=SelectedShipName, _
    After:=ToWorksheet.Range("Y1"), _
    LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=True _
).Row

'Debug.Print ShipRow

StartRow = 14

If ShipRow > 1 Then
    StartRow = (RowMultiplyer * (ShipRow - 1)) + StartRow
Else
    StartRow = 14
End If

Set WorkingRange = ToWorksheet.Range("B" & StartRow & ":G" & StartRow + 38)
Set SystemCol = WorkingRange.Columns(2)

'Debug.Print WorkingRange.Address

FilterName = "Excel Files (*.xls), *.xls,Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx,All Files (*.*), *.*"
TitleString = "Scan File Selection"

For Each SystemName In SystemCol.Cells
    If IsError(SystemName) Then
        Exit For
    Else
        If SystemName.Offset(0, -1) > 1 Then
            MsgBox _
                Prompt:=SystemName & " is marked 'Do Not Scan'", _
                Title:="Do Not Scan"
            GoTo NextIteration
        Else
            MsgSelection = MsgBox( _
                Prompt:="Please select the scan file for the system: " & SystemName, _
                Buttons:=vbOKCancel, _
                Title:=TitleString)
            If MsgSelection = vbOK Then
                FromWorkbook = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
                    FileFilter:=FilterName, _
                    FilterIndex:=2, _
                    Title:=TitleString)
                If FromWorkbook Is Nothing Then
                    MsgSelection = MsgBox( _
                        Prompt:="Does the following system " & SystemName & " have a scan file?", _
                        Buttons:=vbYesNo, _
                        Title:=TitleString)
                    If MsgSelection = vbYes Then
                        FromWorkbook = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
                            FileFilter:=FilterName, _
                            FilterIndex:=2, _
                            Title:=TitleString)
                    Else
                        SystemName.Offset(0, 1).Value2 = 0
                        SystemName.Offset(0, 2).Value2 = 0
                        SystemName.Offset(0, 3).Value2 = 0
                        SystemName.Offset(0, 4).Value2 = 0
                    End If
                Else
                End If
            End If
        End If
        Debug.Print SystemName
    End If
NextIteration:
Next SystemName
```

Comment: did you compile? probably missing an `End If` on your `IF` block (I know the error message talks about a `With block`) ...

Comment: According to the documentation, `Application.GetOpenFilename` returns the path of the file without actually opening it. You may need to store the file path returned by `Application.GetOpenFilename` then do a separate `FromWorkbook = Workbooks.Open FileName:=filePathVariable`. Where `filePathVariable` stores the return value from `GetOpenFilename`.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman: Thank you. I think I figured it out. I used the wrong variable. I used the Workbook variable instead of the Variant one.

Answer (score 0):

The wrong variable was used. Both a variant and a workbook variable are declared. The variant should been used but the workbook variable was used.